# Coulomb scattering amplitude in terms of phase shifts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I am reading Introductory Nuclear Physics by Wong. In Appendix B-2, he shows that the Coulomb scattering amplitude is given by
$$
f^c(\theta)
=
-\frac{\gamma}{2k\sin^2(\theta/2)}
e^{i[\gamma\ln(\sin^2\theta/2) + 2\sigma_0]}
$$
where
$$
k^2 = \frac{2\mu E}{\hbar^2},
\qquad
\gamma = \frac{Z_1 Z_2 \alpha\mu c}{\hbar k},
\qquad
\sigma_\ell = \arg\Gamma(\ell + 1 + i\gamma)
$$
are parameters in the Schrodinger equation
$$
\left(
\nabla^2 + k^2 - \frac{2\gamma k}{r}
\right)\psi_c(r) = 0.
$$
In the same section Wong gives the Coulomb scattering amplitude in terms of phase shifts
$$
f^c(\theta)
=
\frac{1}{2ik}
\sum_{\ell}
(2\ell + 1) (e^{2i\sigma_\ell} - 1) P_\ell(\cos\theta). 
$$

Usually, one can invert a partial wave expansion by using the orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials, i.e.,
$$
\frac{e^{2i\sigma_\ell} - 1}{ik}
=
\int_{-1}^{1}P_\ell(\cos\theta)f^c(\theta)\ d\cos\theta
$$
However, computing the integral using the explicit expression for $f^c(\theta)$ seems problematic. In fact, I am not even sure if the integral converges on the interval of integration.

I have also tried to evaluate both expressions numerically (summing to large values of $\ell$) and the two expressions don't seem to match.

Are these two expressions for $f^c(\theta)$ in fact the same? How do you preform the integral of $f^c(\theta)$?